# 'Record Type ID: this ID value isn't valid for the user:' error occurs in Lightning mode for Opportunity creation on VF page

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lightning-ready

We are using standard Salesforce action (`$Action.Opportunity.New`) on custom VF page for Opportunity creation. It works fine in Classic mode but not in Lightning mode.In Lightning mode it shows record type selection. It allows to select available record type. On clicking continue it shows record creation popup, but inside popup it always shows page layout assigned for master record type. Then on clicking save button it shows

> Record Type ID: this ID value isn't valid for the user:

Please, can anyone help me?

Comment: were you able to fix this?